# Reading line by line in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read from standard input line by line, and process each line with the function of the type `foo :: String -> Int`. Is there any way to do that provided that we don't know the number of lines we want to read OR given that the number of lines is provided on the first line?

**What I've tried**
A lot of things that give meaningless errors, such as "parser error".
For example

```
main = do {
    getLine <- getContents;
    let result = show (foo getLine);
    putStrLn (foo result);
}
```

**Edit**
Strange, but this does not print the length of a

```
main = do {
    a <- getContents;
    putStrLn (show (length a));
}
```

but, this does print 5.

```
main = do {
    a <- getContents;
    putStrLn (show 5);
}
```

Comment: `getLine` is a built-in function in haskell, consider naming your variable something else? Also `do` notation doesn't need `{}`

Answer (score 3):

The main example of doing that will look as this:

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    yourfunction line
    main
```

this will take lines forever and process them with your function, in case you want it to stop sometime, just check for a command for example:

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let res = yourfunction line
    if res == "Exit" then IO () else main
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the function `lines` to convert the String into [String]. Afterwards `map` your `foo` over this list of lines.

Regarding the edit: Your program printing the length works for me. Try either inputting a file or - if entering input interactively - terminating it correctly (via Ctrl-d).

Sidenote: curly brackets and semicolons are rarely seen usually. But this is just style.